# Do you know (that woman who is talking)? / (that woman talking)?

Tags: relative-clauses, participle-phrases

I just studied about relative clauses and I know that they should tell us which person or thing the speaker means. So when I'm in a conference and a woman is speaking can I ask my friend

> "Do you know that woman who is speaking?"

or should I say

> "Do you know that woman speaking?"

or when someone is talking to my friend Tom can I ask my friend

> "Do you know the woman who is talking to Tom?"

or should I say

> "Do you know the woman talking to Tom?"

and why? When should I use relative clause and when -ing and -ed phrases?

Comment: Preliminary point: The -_ing_ and -_ed_ expressions that you refer to are not phrases but non-finite clauses. That aside, it's largely a free choice, though in many instances the non-finite clause alternant is more elegant and often preferred.

Comment: In addition to BillJ's guidance, there are contexts where the meaning between the two constructions differs, as in: **Did you hear the the trumpeter playing the solo?** and **Did you hear the trumpeter who is playing the solo?**

Comment: 'talking to Tom' is a reduced clause. It can also be said a Non-finite clause. You can find more info by searching Reduced clause.

Answer (score 1):

They both work. Adding the "who is", which is usually contracted to "who's", sounds slightly better to me, but omitting it is perfectly functional.